# Where is the standard place to leave a Json file for an app when working on a mobile app?

Tags: c#, android, json, rest, xamarin.android

I am developing a mobile app to connect to a centralized web-server, this app use a login sistem to do that, and i like to save the credentials in a file inside the mobile phone so the user doesn't need to make manualy the log-in every single time is connecting to the app.

For your tranquility, yes, the conection is API REST, AND the credentials are going to be sended for every operation, BUT the data Receiver of the web-server is well controled in a security level.

then what i want it to save user login info (the user on the mobile app) localy in order to send the data every time it will be needed to be sended,
for that i think in save it to a JSON file in some folder, so...

**the question is:**

What folder that should it be?

I think i probably can make it anywhere, but if you provide the path where, by standard -or at least by good practice- must be store, then i pretty much take that like the answer of my question (specialy if do it there is safer than in any other place inside the mobile phone)

Idealy it must be a place where, when the app is uninstalled, the file also be removed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)- there should be xamarin way to handle those, but still I wouldn't suggest to store password.. You should be using accesstokens instead something like [jwt](https://jwt.io/) to securely access server. On rooted device anyone can access your stored data

Comment: yeah but the things than that login give access are not that important anyway, trust me on that one, in any case i'm gonna give it a look to jwt, thanks. ;)

Comment: Still, i'm very intresting in this question to be answer nonetheless, because i think (i supposed) than the answer of this is gonna be also the answer to where to save any file you need to save in the future.

Comment: on different vendors the path might be different. There's article about [saving files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). For storing a lot of data local database is mostly better(find information about android and sqlite)- there are different libraries that help you like [sqlbrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite) or alternatives like [realm](https://realm.io/)

Comment: I keep forgetting that you're using xamarin. But still there are ways to get correct path for you filesystem. Look into [IOS and Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#iOS_and_Android) part of this article and about databases -[Create a Database with SQLite](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/)